# Public Variable Returns Null

Tags: controller, getter, setter

I am trying to return a JSON string to my controller for rendering on a Visualforce page. The query builds correctly and the JSON string builds locally within the method buildQuery.

However my top level public string agricultureContacts still returns null. I am confused as it is public.

Clearly I am missing something fundamental here, shouldn't the method assign the string a value?

```
public class example_Controller {

    public boolean booleanFlag {get; set;}
    public String agricultureContacts {get; set;}


    public PageReference buildQuery(){

        String userQuery = 'SELECT LastName, FirstName FROM Contact WHERE FirstName != null' + ' AND Agriculture__c = ' + booleanFlag;

        List<Contact> returnedContacts = database.query(returnedQuery);
        String agricultureContacts = JSON.serialize(userContacts);

        system.debug(agricultureContacts);

        PageReference pageRef = ApexPages.currentPage();
        return pageRef;
    }         
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have declared both a local and class variable, remove the local declaration in your method

```
public class example_Controller {

public boolean booleanFlag {get; set;}
public String agricultureContacts {get; set;}


public PageReference buildQuery(){

    String userQuery = 'SELECT LastName, FirstName FROM Contact WHERE FirstName != null' + ' AND Agriculture__c = ' + booleanFlag;

    List<Contact> returnedContacts = database.query(returnedQuery);
    agricultureContacts = JSON.serialize(userContacts); //CHANGE HERE

    system.debug(agricultureContacts);

    PageReference pageRef = ApexPages.currentPage();
    return pageRef;

}         
}
```

You had used *String* in front of `agricultureContacts` in the method which made it a local variable and the value was assigned to it instead of the class variable with the same name

Comment: @ManifestDestiny - We have all been there and done that. We tend to revisit once in a while too depending on the day lol...

Answer (score 5):

Adding to Eric's answer, the technical name for what you have done here (declaring a variable with the same name in an inner scope) is called "shadowing".

```
public class MyClass{
    // This property and class variable (respectively) are declared in the Class' scope.
    // In this example, this is the outermost scope.
    public String myStringVar {get;set;}
    public String myOtherStringVar;

    public MyClass(){
        myStringVar = 'abc';
        myOtherStringVar = null;
    }

    public void myMethod(){
        // These variables have the same name, but are in a sub-scope of the class.
        // These variables are said to "shadow" the variables we've defined in the class scope
        String myStringVar = '123';
        String myOtherStringVar = '456';

        system.debug(myStringVar);        // Will output '123'
        system.debug(myOtherStringVar);   // Will output '456'
    }

    public void myOtherMethod(){
        // Since this method has its own scope, and we haven't shadowed the variables
        //   in this scope...

        system.debug(myStringVar);        // Will output 'abc'
        system.debug(myOtherStringVar);   // Will output null
    }
}
```

In most languages (I don't have any counterexamples), when we run into a variable name, the system will look for a declaration for that variable name starting in the current scope. If a declaration isn't found in the current scope, the system looks for a declaration in the next larger scope (in this example, the scope of the Class itself). This continues until a declaration is found, and you get an error if you reach the highest-level scope and still haven't found a declaration.

So when you shadowed `agricultureContacts`, the value was set on the variable instance contained in the scope of your method. `agricultureContacts` at the class level remains uninitialized, and when you try to get the value, you get null.

In this simple case, Eric's answer (which removes the `String` keyword from `agricultureContacts` in your method) is all that needed to be done to get your controller working as expected.

Sometimes, you may want to shadow variables. Maybe `agricultureContacts` is the most descriptive, most concise name to use, and anything else would be confusing or cumbersome (naming things is, after all, [one of the 2 hard problems in computer science](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TwoHardThings.html)...right up there with cache invalidation and off-by-one errors).

In this situation, where you shadow a class-level variable in a method scope (or some sub-scope of a method), you can still access the variable in the class-level scope by using the `this` keyword.

```
public void myMethod(){
    // These variables have the same name, but are in a sub-scope of the class.
    // These variables are said to "shadow" the variables we've defined in the class scope
    String myStringVar = '123';
    String myOtherStringVar = '456';

    system.debug(myStringVar);            // Will output '123'
    system.debug(myOtherStringVar);       // Will output '456'

    // Getting at the variable in the Class' outermost scope, when
    //   variables are shadowed, requires using 'this'
    system.debug(this.myStringVar);       // Will output 'abc'
    system.debug(this.myOtherStringVar);  // Will output null
}
```